# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'File' of 'value'

Tags: flutter

When I'm trying to add a images to listview dynamically to show a multiple images from camera picker.
How can I add the list of images to list view to show an image.

Code for clicking image:

```
 Future getImage() async {
File images;
File  _images = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  setState(() {

    images =  _images;
    image.add(images.path);

  });
}
```

Then in futurebuilder:

```
                child: new ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
                  {

                    print(image[index].toString());
                    return new UserWidgets(imageURL: 
                    image[index].toString());

                  },
                  itemCount: image.length,
                ),
              ),
              ),
```

Then my viewcode like this:

```
class UserWidgets extends StatelessWidget
 {
 final String imageURL;
  // final String imageType;
  const UserWidgets  ({Key key, this.imageURL}) : super(key: key);

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  //   print(this.imageType);
   VideoPlayerController playerController;
  VoidCallback listener;
     Widget play=new Icon(Icons.play_arrow);
   Widget pause=new Icon(Icons.pause);

   new Container(
  height: 200.0,
  child: new Card(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: ()
            {


            },
            child:
            new  Image.file(  File(imageURL)
              ,fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 200.0,
              width: 150.0,

            ),

          )
        ],
      )
  ),
)
            },
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
List<File> images = [];
```

instead of

```
File images;
```

with

```
File  _image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  setState(() {
    images.add(_image);
  });
}
```

Comment: where does image comes? image or _image?

Comment: Sorry, forgot `_`

Comment: its creating a empty card ,,,, error thrown  like :      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:368:9)

Comment: Change `image[index].toString()` to `image[index]` and `final String imageURL;` to `final File imageURL;` and `new  Image.file(  File(imageURL))` to `new  Image.file(imageURL)`. or use `List<String> images = [];` with ` images.add(_image.path);` and leave the rest.

Comment: when i add this   List<String> images = []; and  images.add(_image.path) ,, its also shown my question only

Comment: Hard to tell from here.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I also have same problem I opened issue in github but you closed and directed to these channel. there is a problem with adding objects to lists and there is no exact solution for that issue

Comment: Please create a new question with proper information (code that demonstrates what you tried, expected behavior, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Use `XFile?`  with `pickImage()` to pick image.

```dart
final XFile? image= await ImagePicker().pickImage(
  source: ImageSource.camera,
 );
```

And to display the value use

```dart
 if(image!=null) Image.file(File(image.path)),
```